# Android RandomAccessFile from Assets directory

Tags: android, xml

I would like to port some code to Android(more pecisely an XML parser net.xqhs.util.XML ) in order to do that I need to read files from assets or raw folder using RandomAccessFile.

How can I do this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

That is not possible, sorry. Neither an asset nor a resource is a file on the Android device, and so while you can get an `InputStream` on them, you cannot create a `RandomAccessFile` on them.

Your choices are:

1. Use any of the available XML parsers for Android that take an `InputStream`. There are three XML parsers that are part of Android (DOM, SAX, `XmlPullParser`) that can work with streams. I would expect [most of the third-party XML parsers](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/114) to also support `InputStream`.
2. Copy the asset or raw resource (e.g., using an `InputStream`) to a local file. Then, create a `RandomAccessFile` for that file.

Comment: Can you detail please the second option, how do I copy the file locally

Comment: @IonutCosminMihai: For an asset, use `AssetManager` and `open()` to get an `InputStream` on the asset. Use something like `new FileOutputStream(new File(getFilesDir(), 'something.xml'))` to get an `OutputStream` on your desired file. Then, use standard Java I/O to copy from the `InputStream` to the `OutputStream`.